# On a paper of Alain Connes entitled 'Around Wilson's Theorem '

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem, analytic-functions

A relatively recent paper [Alain Connes - Around Wilson's theorem](https://www.alainconnes.org/docs/wilsonarXiv.pdf) 
introduced the function 
$$
S(n,x ) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \sin^2\Bigl(\frac{(i-1)! x}{i}\Bigr).
$$
In the same paper, he proved that the integer part of    $S(n, \pi/2)$ represents the  prime counting function $\pi(n)$.

Can we bound the sum  $S(n,x)$,  or at least get prime number theorem from  $S(n, \pi/2)$?

Comment: It is not news that you can use trig functions and Wilson's Theorem to count primes, see, e.g., https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/p_n.html If such formulas were of any use in deriving the Prime Number Theorem I suspect we would have known about it long ago.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I also know that there's various formulas . But they only use zeroes and ones for counting i.e. distributional sense . But I think the above formula is something different than all others; So I've cared to ask

Comment: I second that said the previous professor (in fact I was tempted to write this comment yesterday). On the other hand see the last paragraph of page 432, or the penultimate paragraph of page 434 from Leonard Eugene Dickson, *History of the Theory  of Numbers*, Volume I Divisibility and Primality, Dover Publications 2005.